# Jenkins MSBuild fails, error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, version 2.9.3 was not found

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to deploy a sample aspnet core project but Jenkins build fails.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,
5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers, version 2.9.3 was not found. It might have
 been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which 
might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test\ProductCoreApi\ProductCoreApi.csproj]
```

I'm using VS2019. I removed and reinstalled the package and tried all possible measures. Still unable to get an idea of what went wrong. The project is in github. Any idea on what went wrong?

Comment: did you made any progress on this? I am having the same issue, it gives me gray hair ahead of time.
if I build it from command line with the same command the jenkins slave is using it succeeds :(

Comment: I just delete the whole directory so that I manually clean the bin/obj/packages folders.  That seems to do the trick.  If you need to debug further, I recommend MSbuildStructuredLogViewer tool and running your build with binary logging mode enabled so you can record EVERYTHING that happens.

Comment: Faced with the same problem. Added "/restore" option to msbuild.exe command and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Path of Project and Run
**dotnet restore**

or Use  MSBuild /t:restore
[Check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target)

Answer (score 0):

ok so for me it turned out that the jenkins slave I was running under the system account instead of Admin account.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when trying to build a solution through an MSBuild script.
There's a problematic section in one of the `.csproj` files:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    ....
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.2.9.4"...> 
    </Error>
    ...
</Target>
```

When it was removed, I could continue running the build.
The packages it complains about are all there.

Answer (score 0):

jenkins->manage -> GTC->MSBuild -> Default Parameter: (add) /t:restore

[image: Default parameters: /t:restore]

Answer (score 0):

I removed all Nuget packages with this command

```
dotnet nuget locals --clear all
```

Then rebuild my solution again.